# Problems detecting SHIFT keys in Java on Windows

Tags: java, awt, keylistener, key-events

I'm writing a simulation of an old machine in Java and I'd like my keyboard handling to treat the left- and right-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> keys independently.

I have a standard AWT `KeyListener` registered and process the `KeyPressed()` and `KeyReleased()` methods.  Here's the problem:

```
1) Press Left-SHIFT  
  -> get KeyPressed() for VK_SHIFT with location=LEFT  ... good!
2) Keep Left-SHIFT held down, press Right-SHIFT too
  -> get KeyPressed() for VK_SHIFT with location=RIGHT ... good!
3) Release Right-SHIFT (left-SHIFT still held down)
  -> get ... absolutely nothing ... bad!
4) Release Left-SHIFT
  -> get KeyReleased() for VK_SHIFT with location=LEFT ... good.
```

So, I have lost the `KeyReleased()`information for right-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>.  This fails in this way when running on Windows, but works correctly (I see all events) on Linux.  Any ideas?  Is this just a Windows anomaly I have to live with.  Curiously it doesn't fail like this with the two <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys—I see all events as I'd hope.

It is easy to reproduce this behaviour using the standard Sun `KeyEventDemo.java` program.

Comment: My guess is "Windows anomaly".  There could be a registry setting that affects this; when I got my desktop, the two Alt keys were behaving differently and I had a good reason for wanting them to be the same, and I found I could fix the registry to make it work.  Yours is a different problem, though.

Comment: @ajb, It's also possible this is a quirk of the physical keyboard in question; Keyboard manufacturers do quite interesting things with the way keys are wired which makes key combinations not always work as expected. The keyboard might not send the "key released" signal because the manufacturer figured "hey, left is still down, why would we bother sending the release signal?" http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2007/03/28/keyboards-suck.aspx

Answer (score 0):

try the following:
      1.Run the same program on some other xp/win7/win8. 2.Run the same program with completely different sets of keyboards. this might solve the issue